# Interface not working Libgdx + Non-Libgdx activity

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx

I want to implement Firebase into my LIBGDX part of my project and need an interface as said in the Tutorial: https://libgdx.com/wiki/app/interfacing-with-platform-specific-code .

I followed the tutiral as best as i could understand (i am a beginner), but it is still not working. I need a variable in my Firebase class for my methods, but i can not use the variable in my launcher class for the LIBGDX part. I resorted to using an Interface because importing the dependencies did not work.

I can not compile thus no error code i can share.

The specific implementations :

```
public class Firebase implements Api {
    private int einsatz;

    public Firebase(int einsatz) {
        this.einsatz = einsatz;
    }

    public void kontostandandernminus(int einsatz) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference();
        mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Long b = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                Long c = b - einsatz;
                mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").setValue(c);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void kontostandpositiv(int einsatz, com.mygdx.game.gamestates.Callback listener) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference();
        mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Long b = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                boolean kontostandPositiv = b >= einsatz;
                listener.Callbackchecked(kontostandPositiv);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                listener.Callbackchecked(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public void kontostandandernplus(int einsatz) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference();
        mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Long b = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                Long c = b + einsatz;
                mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").setValue(c);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void kontostandanzeigen () {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://t-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference();
        mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(encodeUserEmail(email)).child("stand").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Long b = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                String c = b + " ";
                System.out.println(c);
                //ausgabe des Kontostandes

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void changeActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    }
}
```

The Android application launcher:

```
public class peg_launcher extends AndroidApplication {
    private int einsatz;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new Game(einsatz), config);
        new AndroidApplicationConfiguration(new Game(new Firebase(einsatz)), config);
    }

}
```

The interface:

```
public interface Api {
    public void kontostandandernminus(int einsatz);
    public void kontostandpositiv(int einsatz, Callback listener);
    public void kontostandandernplus(int einsatz);
    public void kontostandanzeigen();
    public void changeActivity();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?